# Paralize numpy.linalg.matrix_power do not increase performance

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I need to paralize the function numpy.linalg.matrix_power and I use the following code to test how much fast can be the parallel version

```
def aux_matrix_arg3(A):

     aaa=np.linalg.matrix_power(np.random.randn(199,199),100)    

return 1

N=10000
processes=4
chunksize=N/processes
poolWorkers=mp.Pool(processes=processes)
ti=t.time()
A=poolWorkers.map(aux_matrix_arg3,range(N),chunksize=chunksize)
print 't_iteration 3',t.time()-ti
```

I have tried with 1 and 4 processes in my laptop. I got very similar performance
4 processes: t_iteration 3 40.7985408306
1 processes: t_iteration 3 40.6538720131

Any clue why I do not get any improvment with paralle processes?

Comment: You should check the CPU loads for 1 process vs. 4 processes. Maybe `np.linalg.matrix_power` is already multiprocesses or multithreaded internally.

Comment: You are right! It is already multithread internally.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> For positive integers n, the power is computed by repeated matrix squarings and matrix multiplications. If n == 0, the identity matrix of the same shape as M is returned. If n < 0, the inverse is computed and then raised to the abs(n).

If your system is set up correctly, [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) will be used to parallelize matrix-multiplications and [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) (maybe SuperLU, the latter probably only in the sparse-case) for solving systems of linear-equations (used to calculate the inverse). So with a very high probability, your naive code is already very very optimized!

Despite that, you should be careful as naive parallelization copies all the data, which can hurt. (Normaly one would use mmap-arrays to share data instead of copying).